# MySQL 5.1: How to rollback partitioned table

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.1, partitioning

I have partitioned a table on the basis of one flag column have value either 0 or 1.
Now, I want to roll back these tables.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove the partitioning?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove partitioning and restore it as earlier.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE .... REMOVE PARTITIONING

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html

Only available from version 5.1.8 onwards.